# Does cleaning or filling of teeth breaks fast?

Tags: fiqh, sawm, hanafi

All praises to be Allah SW.

My dentist advised me that I should clean my teeth with the dentist during Ramadan, and they are closed after iftar. So today I went to the dentist at 9:00 AM and he cleaned my teeth there were blood and drugs in my mouth during the cleaning, Should I continue the fasting for today or break it with foods or drink?

Comment: If the tag [tag:hanafi] means you want a fatwa based on the teachings of the hanafi school of fiqh than I'm not sure whether the given answers would fit, if you didn't intend to have only the hanafi view you should delete this tag!

Comment: I will prefer hanafi fiqh but I am not tied  to that.

Comment: By "drugs in my mouth" are you referring to a topical anesthetic (i.e. something you might swallow) or was it an injection? There may be different rulings involved in both of those (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If those things reached your throat, than your fast is invalid, but if not so, than i am pretty sure your fast is valid.** If you properly spitted those drugs and blood out.

Besides this, **i would suggest** you to try to do such things after fasting, change dentist or ask him for special appointment or whatever possible, to avoid any difficulties and doubts when fasting.

> **Imaam Ibn Qudaamah**  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him
>   , said: **'If a fasting person is bleeding in his mouth
>   or has vomit, and he swallows it, his fast is broken** even if it is a
>   small amount, because the ruling that applies to other apparent things
>   apply to the mouth as well. because **the basic principle is that anything that goes from the mouth to the stomach breaks the fast**, with the exception of saliva  as it is
>   difficult to avoid it.' **(Al-Mughni, 4/356)**

Also see [Shiekh bin baz fatwa on Having dental treatment whilst fasting](https://islamqa.info/en/13767)

Comment: Can you give me the reference for the Imam sayings?

Comment: it is from Al-Mughni

Comment: @SayedAhmad see my answer, i updated the quote with better translation and added reference.

Comment: @SayedAhmad let me know the details if this does not answer your question, i will update it. If this answers the question please accept the answer. Jazakallah.

Comment: Brother if you can find something from Hanafi fiqh that will be great, if I couldn't  find answer from hanafi fiqh then I will accept this answer.

Comment: Oh that's the reason... i didn't gave attention to tags, and it was not mentioned in question. I will try to look up for that too.

Comment: @SayedAhmad have a look here, http://islamqa.org/hanafi/seekersguidance-hanafi/31898 it seems hanafi schoalrs have same opinion about blood etc invalidating fast.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, If something got into the flow of your blood or body , like drugs or some ingredients, Your fast is invalid , but you did not have intention to eat so that just after Ramadan fast for a day. If your conscience is okay with that , go on , but If you are not sure exactly, just complete the fast in case Allah will decide if is done rightly. Do your best then do not look back . Also try to ask some professionals. Best regards. Selamın Aleyküm

Comment: Well this is not always the case, scholars have allowed even injections if needed during fasting. You should mention difference of opinion.